# Magento 2 . API: want to fetch only order ID but every order details are coming

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, postman

webapi.xml:

```
 <route url="/V1/orders/" method="GET">
        <service class="SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\OrderedRepositoryInterface" method="getOrderDetails"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

service class of API:

```
<?php

namespace SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Model;

use SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\OrderedRepositoryInterface;
use SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Model\AddDataFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\Data\OrderedInterfaceFactory;

class OrderedRepository implements OrderedRepositoryInterface
{
    public $addDataFactory;
    public $orderFactory;
    public $orderedInterfaceFactory;

    public function __construct(AddDataFactory $addDataFactory,OrderFactory $orderFactory,OrderedInterfaceFactory $orderedInterfaceFactory)
      {
           $this->addDataFactory = $addDataFactory;
           $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
           $this->orderedInterfaceFactory = $orderedInterfaceFactory;



     }
     /**
      *
      *@return \SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\Data\OrderedInterface
      */

        public function getOrderDetails()
         {
           /*$employeeId = 2;
            $custom = $this->addDataFactory->create();
           $obj = $custom->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['customer_id'])->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$employeeId);

            foreach($obj as $id)
            {
            $arr = $id->getData();
            break;

             }
               $var = $arr['customer_id']; //customer id

             $object = $this->orderFactory->create();
             $engg = $object->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['entity_id'])->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$var);
              foreach($engg as $item)
              {
            $array = $item->getData();
            break;

            }
             $var = $array['entity_id']; 

                 $into = $this->OrderedInterfaceFactory->create()->setOrderId($var);
                   return $into;
                   */

                  $emp =   $this->addDataFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['customer_id'])->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',2);
                  foreach($emp as $hit)
                  {
                      $datas = $hit->getData();
                  }
                  $vard = $datas['customer_id'];
                  //var_dump($vard);
                 // echo "</br>";

                 $obj =  $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['entity_id'])->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$vard);
                 foreach($obj as $item)
                 {
                   $arr =  $item->getData();
                     //break;
                 }
                 $var = $arr['entity_id'];
                 //var_dump($var);

                 $into = $this->OrderedInterfaceFactory->create()->setOrderId($var);
                 return $into;



        }









    }









?>
```

Servie interface:

```
<?php

namespace SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api;

Interface OrderedRepositoryInterface
{



     /** 
    * 
    * @return \SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\Data\OrderedInterface
    */

    public function getOrderDetails();

}



?>
```

Data class :

```
 <?php

    namespace SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Model\Data;
    use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
    use SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\Data\OrderedInterface;

    class Ordered extends DataObject  implements OrderedInterface
    {

       /** 
        * @return string
        *
        */
          public function getOrderId()
          {
              return $this->getData('OrderId');
          }






        /** 
        * @param string $orderId
        * @return $this
        */
         public function setOrderId($orderId)
         {
             return $this->setData('OrderId',$orderId);
         }





    }

    ?>
```

Data Interface :

```
<?php

namespace SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Model\Data;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\Data\OrderedInterface;

class Ordered extends DataObject  implements OrderedInterface
{

   /** 
    * @return string
    *
    */
      public function getOrderId()
      {
          return $this->getData('OrderId');
      }






    /** 
    * @param string $orderId
    * @return $this
    */
     public function setOrderId($orderId)
     {
         return $this->setData('OrderId',$orderId);
     }





}

?>
```

service Interfce:

```
<?php

namespace SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api;

Interface OrderedRepositoryInterface
{



     /** 
    * 
    * @return \SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\Data\OrderedInterface
    */

    public function getOrderDetails();

}



?>
```

Comment: please add `searchCriteria` in api endpoint even there is no searchCriteria you want to pass, add like `yourendpint?searchCriteria`, this will solve this error

Comment: <route url="/V1/orders/" method="GET">
        <service class="SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\OrderedRepositoryInterface" method="getOrderDetails"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>

Comment: i did not get you this my webapi.xml file

Comment: I guess this is your custom API please share rest of the files for proper solutions

Comment: yes.  i have posted my service class

Comment: @AnkurAnand add your url like this `base_url/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria` and check

Comment: that error is gone....But i only want to fetch "orderid" But every Order details are coming.....I will put my other files as well